# Spline Graph with diagonally fixed values with 0,0 and ploting remaing same

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

We are using Spline Graph for our game in which we are facing issue with x and y axis value which we need to put 0,0 and save the values from initially till end as we need to all plotting from start till end of the value.

**[Check Live Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sadikhasan786/gpacLywk/)**

[image]

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script>
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
var factor = 1.2;
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () { 
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        b = b*1.2;
                        console.log(b);
                        var x = a; // current time
                        var y = b;
                            a++;
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 700);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'number',
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: 2
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>X: ' + this.x+', Y:'+this.y;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],i;
                for (i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {
                        b = b*factor;
                        data.push({
                            x: a,
                            y: b
                        });
                        a++;            
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code so people know what you're trying?

Comment: @Razzildinho Check my edited question with sample code

Comment: @Razzildinho Check my code I also updated my demo url.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code draws a curve line from the origin (0,0) to the end point which gets updated on the interval. You needed to make the `shift` variable `false` in the `addPoint` call. [Higchart docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var a = 1;
    var b = 1;
    var factor = 1.2;

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () { 
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        b = b*1.2;
                        var x = a; // current time
                        var y = b;
                        a++;
                        // Add new end point
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
                    }, 700);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'number',
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: 2
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>X: ' + this.x+', Y:'+this.y;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                // Add point at origin and last point of series
                var data = [{x:0,y:0}],i;
                for (i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {
                    b = b*factor;
                    a++
                    data.push({
                        x: a,
                        y: b
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
});
```

[Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpacLywk/2/)

Comment: I need curve line diagonally  with all points which I got through function.

Comment: @Sadikhasan do you want a curve or a diagonal?

Comment: I want curve starting from (0,0) to end. I got curve as mentioned in image but not from (0,0)

Comment: @Sadikhasan you just needed to change to `series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);` to not remove the first points. Answer updated.

Comment: Exactly that I want. Thanks dear.